# Android : Progressbar to load url, continues to load

Tags: android

In my application, i'm using a webview to open a url. The url is very simple, it just takes secs to load. But the progress bar doesn't hide when the url loads completely. I'm not able to figure out whats wrong. please help me. Below i'm posting the code.

WebView Class

```
public class noti_cse extends BaseActivity {
    private WebView webView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.noti_cse);
        //  overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

        //  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webcse);
        //  webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webcse);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.clearHistory();
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            startWebView("http://notify.php");
        }


        // webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //  startWebView("http://notify.php");
        // webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

        // webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);


    }


    private void startWebView(String url) {

        //Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
        //When opening a url or click on link

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            //Show loader on url load
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    // in standard case YourActivity.this
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(noti_cse.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("On the Way!!!");
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                try {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);

    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(noti_cse.this)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean useDrawerToggle() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_placements)
            return true;

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
            onBackPressed();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting 2 WebViewClient.

First:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

And after that, you are calling

```
startWebView()
```

which sets a new WebviewClient.

You can change your method like below:

```
private void startWebView(String url) {

    //Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
    //When opening a url or click on link

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(noti_cse.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }

        //Show loader on url load
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(noti_cse.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("On the Way!!!");
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

}
```

And remove this line form onCreate() method:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```